# Please help me to create statement level trigger in mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-workbench

```
+-------+-------+--------+
| EmpID | EName | Salary |
+-------+-------+--------+
|     1 | Preet | 100000 |
|     2 | Sahil | 150000 |
|     3 | Bill  |  90000 |
|     4 | Lisa  | 120000 |
|     5 | Mukul | 100000 |
+-------+-------+--------+
```

This is the table

I was trying to create statement level trigger to update salary of employee with id=3 by +10000 whenever the insert or update operation is called.

```
mysql> create trigger stmt_level
    -> before update on employee
    -> begin
    -> update employee set salary=salary+10000 where EmpID=3;
    -> end;
    -> $$
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'begin
> update employee set salary=salary+10000 where EmpID=3;
> end' at line 3

Comment: You cannot pertform any action over the table on which the trigger is defined on. So describe the task, not the way which you decide to use for this task to be solved.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not support statement-level triggers like for example [Oracle](https://www.oracletutorial.com/plsql-tutorial/oracle-statement-level-triggers/).

You can only create triggers in MySQL that execute once for each row updated. You must use the `FOR EACH ROW` clause before `BEGIN`:

```
create trigger row_level
before update on employee
for each row begin
    ...do something with one updated row...
end
```

Comment: 1) `.. on employee .. update employee ..` - not allowed 2) Shown statement tries to update the whole table despite of updated row.

Comment: Yes, there are logical problems with the trigger as written, but my answer is meant to address only the issue of statement-level trigger versus row-level trigger.

Comment: Feel free to post an answer of your own.

Comment: I wait for OP answers on my comment and describes the task.

Comment: I have edited my example trigger to be more generic, and avoid the illogical implementation.

Comment: so this means that mysql doesnt support statement level triggers !!

Comment: I was trying to create statement level trigger that updates the salary of the employee with id=3 by +10000 whenever insert is done.

Comment: Right, there is no support for statement-level triggers in MySQL. It does not have that feature.